# hibernate core jar on Play! framework doesn't match

Tags: hibernate, playframework

It all started when I had problems with `orphanRemoval` on Play! framework 1.3.0, then - when debugged `hibernate-core` jar I saw the bytecode doesn't match the source code I downloaded from grepcode.

Then - after another look, I saw that the same hibernate-core jar distributed with play 1.3.0 isn't the same as the one on Jboss comunity repository, and the on the repository fixes all issues !

Any ideas on what's going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently, Play framework is using a patched version of hibernate core.
Can be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.19.Final-patched-play-1.3.2), for example.